# Error report: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index: : 1. How can I fix that?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

```
set serveroutput on;

Declare
  cursor emp_cursor is select orderline.orderid, sum(product.productstandardprice * orderline.orderedquantity) AS price from orderline, Product WHERE orderline.Productid = Product.Productid group by orderline.orderid;
  emp_row emp_cursor%rowtype;

Begin
  open emp_cursor;
  if (price < 2,000)

  then price := 2,000 * 0.15:

  else if (price >= 2,000)

  then price := 2,000 * 0.20; 

  loop
    fetch emp_cursor into emp_row;
    exit when emp_cursor%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(emp_row.orderid || ' ' || emp_row.price);
  end loop;
  close emp_cursor;

End;
```

Comment: After 0.15, it should be a semi-colon.

Comment: Price does exist. It was created as an alias in the statement under Declare. I checked the program to make sure it will work before I started putting the if statements and it did work. Only after putting the if statements did I start to run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a colon after 0.15.  That should be a semi-colon.
2. Numeric literals should not have embedded commas.
3. Your `IF` statement comes before you've fetched anything from the cursor.  Perhaps you want that statement to be inside the loop after the `EXIT` statement?
4. Your `IF` statement is referring to a variable `price` that does not exist.  Perhaps you want to refer to `emp_row.price`?
5. The syntax for an `IF` statement is `IF ... THEN ... ELSIF ... END IF`.  You are missing the `END IF` and you either want to combine the `else if` into a single `elsif` or have two separate `IF` statements and two separate `END IF` statements.

There may be additional syntax errors that I'm not seeing.  It is always helpful to post the DDL to create your tables, the DML to populate the data, and the expected results.  That allows us to test on our system and makes it more likely that we'll catch all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If-else statement ends with `END IF;`

Try to put that in and run.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps...

```
Declare

cursor emp_cursor is select orderline.orderid, sum(product.productstandardprice * orderline.orderedquantity) AS price from orderline, Product WHERE orderline.Productid = Product.Productid group by orderline.orderid;

emp_row emp_cursor%rowtype;

Begin

  open emp_cursor;

  loop

    fetch emp_cursor into emp_row;
    exit when emp_cursor%notfound;

    if  emp_row.price < 2000 then
        emp_row.price := 2000 * 0.15;
    elsif emp_row.price >= 2000 then
        emp_row.price := 2000 * 0.20; 
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line(emp_row.orderid || ' ' || emp_row.price);

  end loop;

  close emp_cursor;

End;
```